# Find $E[(X+Y)^2]$ given $E(X^2)=3$ $E(Y^2)=4$ and $E(XY) = 2$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I know this is an easy question but I'm having problems solving it

I sorta thought that you'd get $E(X^2) + 2E(XY) + E(Y^2)$ and that'd add up to: $3+4+4=11$ but my answer isn't correct. I'm guessing my intuition is definitely wrong

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe the answer is 11. What makes you say it's incorrect?

Comment: The first term in your title is: $[E(X+Y)]^2$ or $E[(X+Y)^2]$?

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I must've slipped up

Answer (score 1):

First, observe that we have
$E((X+Y)^2) = E(X^2 + 2XY + Y^2)$

The key property that we will use is **Linearity of expectation**. This says for any random variables $X$ and $Y$, and any constants $a$ and $b$, we have
$$E(aX + bY) = aE(X) + bE(Y)$$
Applying this to what we did above, we get
$$E(X^2 + 2XY + Y^2) = E(X^2) + 2E(XY) + E(Y^2)$$
So your initial thought was correct.